# $x \in \bar A$ iff $\exists (x_\lambda) \subset A$ net with $(x_\lambda) \to x$

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, nets

$x \in \bar A$ $\iff$ $\exists (x_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \subset A$ net with $(x_\lambda) \to x$

What I did:

$\Leftarrow$: Let $(x_\lambda) \subset A$ a net with $(x_\lambda) \to x$. Let $V$ an open set with $x \in V$, then $\exists \lambda_0 \in \Lambda$ with $\forall \lambda \geq \lambda_0$, $x_\lambda \in V$. But $x_{\lambda} \in A, \forall \lambda \geq \lambda_0$. Then $A \cap V$ isn't empty. So $x \in \bar A$

$\Rightarrow$: I don't know how to proceed in this side. Could someone give a hint of what net I should get?

Comment: Hint: Let $(x_U)_{U}$ be a net, $x_U \in U\cap A$,  indexed by open neighborhoods $U$ of $x$, and show that this converges to $x$. This example is also given in the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take as the indexing family $\Lambda$ the family of all open neighbourhoods of $x$, ordered by inclusion. Since $x\in \bar{A}$, there is for every $U\in\Lambda$ an $x_U\in A\cap U$. The net $x_U$ converges to $x$.

Comment: You should order by **reverse** inclusion. So $U \le V$ iff $V \subseteq U$. In that case, for any neighbourhood $O$, we take $\lambda_0 = O$ and if $U \ge \lambda_0= O$, then $U \subseteq O$. Hence $x_U \in U \subseteq O$ for all those $U$, as required.